# python laplace filter returns wrong values

Tags: python, image, filter, python-imaging-library, edge-detection

As I need to implement a sort of image processing program in python I also wanted to implement the laplace filter. I used the matrix
-1 -1 -1 
-1  8 -1
-1 -1 -1

and implemented the following code:

```
    for row in range(1, (len(self._dataIn) - 1)):
         for col in range(1, (len(self._dataIn[row])- 1)):
             value =  (- int(self._dataIn[row - 1][col -1][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row - 1][col][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row - 1][col + 1][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row][col -1][0]) + 
                       (8 * int(self._dataIn[row][col][0]))
                       - int(self._dataIn[row][col +1][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row + 1][col -1][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row + 1][col][0])
                       - int(self._dataIn[row + 1][col +1][0]))
             self._dataIn[row][col][0] = np.minimum(255, np.maximum(0, value))
             self._dataIn[row][col][1] = np.minimum(255, np.maximum(0, value))
             self._dataIn[row][col][2] = np.minimum(255, np.maximum(0, value))
    self.update()
```

self._dataIn is the image array. In another method I converted the image to

```
np.array(img)
```

and after processing the filter method, I reconvert the image using

```
Image.fromarray(...)
```

But when I start the program, it returns a strange result:
[image]

I already have changed my code lots of time but can't figure out, what I'm doing wrong. Is there something wrong with my implementation? Or do I misunderstand the filter?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must not modify the array in place, i.e. if you are applying the filter to `self._dataIn`, then you must not store the result in `self._dataIn` because on the next filter operation, the input will not be the correct one.

By the way, it is easier to use `numpy` matrix multiplication to do the filtering (and to use a one component image):

```
img = img.mean(2) # get a NxM image
imgOut = np.zeros (img.shape, dtype = uint8)
M = np.array([
    [-1, -1, -1], 
    [-1,  8, -1], 
    [-1, -1, -1]
])
for row in range(1, img.shape[0] - 1):
    for col in range(1, img.shape[1] - 1):
        value = M * img[(row - 1):(row + 2), (col - 1):(col + 2)]
        imgOut[row, col] = min(255, max(0, value.sum ()))
```

Result:

[image] [image]