# Python matrix convolution without using numpy.convolve or scipy equivalent functions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, convolution

I need to write a matrix convolution without using any built in functions to help. I am taking an image and turning it to greyscale, and then I'm supposed to pass a filter matrix over it. One of the filter matrices I have to use is:

```
[[-1,0,1],
[-1,0,1],
[-1,0,1]]
```

I understand how convolutions work, I just don't understand how to apply the convolution with code. Here is the code I am using to get my greyscale array:

```
import numpy
from scipy import misc
mylist = []
for i in myfile:
    mylist.append(i)

for i in mylist:
    q = i
    print(q)
    image = misc.imread(q[0:-1])
    threshold()
image = misc.imread('image1.png')


def averageArr(pixel): #make the pixel color values more realistic
    return 0.299*pixel[:,:,0] + 0.587*pixel[:,:,1] + 0.114*pixel[:,:,2]

def threshold():
    picture = averageArr(image)
    for i in range(0,picture.shape[0]): #begin thresholding 
        for j in range(0,picture.shape[1]):
            myList.append(i,j)
    misc.imsave('image1.png') #save the image file
```

I take the values from the function, and add them to a list, and then I am supposed to iterate over the list, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. I can use scipy and numpy to read and arrange the matrix, but the actual convolution function has to be written.

Comment: But this is not a question, is it?

Comment: Hi, my question is how to convolve the matrix with the filter. I cannot figure out how to apply it to each of the pixels in the matrix that is generated by the image.

Comment: Check out the Cython documentation. The Cython bit is best ignored for your assignment, but the tutorial starts from a plain Python implementation of a 2d convolution: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/numpy.html

Comment: "`I need to write a matrix convolution without using any built in functions to help.`" --> why are built-in functions unavailable?

Comment: Built in functions are unavailable because it's an assignment for my robotics course and he wants us to do it from scratch. I've done a bunch of them on paper for exercises, but I was having problems getting the iterations to work for each value in my matrices. The course is very concept heavy, and very light on coding instruction.

Comment: @ZachWilcox Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31615554/python-laplace-filter-returns-wrong-values/31616092#31616092), it should give you a start.

Comment: @Holt excellent, thank you very much!